# Python gets into an infinite loop that does nothing

Tags: python

I don't know why it's happening but basically after python should end a while, it does nothing (but the program doesn't finish) and I can see the program is using processor as if it was an infinite loop.

I have no clue why it happens, it wasn't happening before and I think I haven't changed anything on the function that's causing this issue.

Code:

```
import random


class Gato:

    movimiento = 0
    posicion = [0, 0]

    def spawn(self):
        self.posicion = [random.randint(0, 4), random.randint(0, 4)]

    def moverse(self, direccion):
        movido = False

        while not movido:
            if direccion == "sur":
                if self.posicion[1] == 4:
                    print("No puedes salir de los limites del mapa")
                    direccion = input("Vuelve a moverte en una dirección (norte, este, oeste)")
                else:
                    self.posicion[1] += 1
                    self.movimiento += 1
                    movido = True
            elif direccion == "norte":
                if self.posicion[1] == 0:
                    print("No puedes salir de los limites del mapa")
                    direccion = input("Vuelve a moverte en una dirección (sur, este, oeste)")
                else:
                    self.posicion[1] -= 1
                    self.movimiento += 1
                    movido = True
            elif direccion == "este":
                if self.posicion[0] == 4:
                    print("No puedes salir de los limites del mapa")
                    direccion = input("Vuelve a moverte en una dirección (norte, sur, oeste)")
                else:
                    self.posicion[0] += 1
                    self.movimiento += 1
                    movido = True
            elif direccion == "oeste":
                if self.posicion[0] == 0:
                    print("No puedes salir de los limites del mapa")
                    direccion = input("Vuelve a moverte en una dirección (norte, sur, este)")
                else:
                    self.posicion[0] -= 1
                    self.movimiento += 1
                    movido = True
            else:
                print("Esa no es una direccion válida")
                direccion = input("Vuelve a moverte en una dirección (norte, sur, este)")

    def detectarcolisionraton(self, raton):
        if self.posicion == raton.getposicion():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def detectarcolisionqueso(self, queso):
        if self.posicion == queso.getposicion():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def getmovimientos(self):
        return self.movimiento

    def checklimites(self, dir):
        if self.posicion[1] == 4 & dir == 0:
            print("No puedes salir de los limites del mapa")
        elif self.posicion[1] == 0 & dir == 1:
            print("No puedes salir de los limites del mapa")
        elif self.posicion[0] == 0 & dir == 2:
            print("No puedes salir de los limites del mapa")
        elif self.posicion[0] == 4 & dir == 3:
            print("No puedes salir de los limites del mapa")


class Raton:

    posicion = [0, 0]

    def spawn(self):
        self.posicion = [random.randint(0, 4), random.randint(0, 4)]

    def getposicion(self):
        return self.posicion

    def moverse(self, gato):
        xory = random.randint(0, 1)
        rand = random.randint(0, 1)
        movido = False

        while not movido:
            if gato.getmovimientos() % 3 == 0:
                if xory == 0:
                    if rand == 0:
                        if self.posicion[0] == 4:
                            xory = random.randint(0, 1)
                            rand = random.randint(0, 1)
                        else:
                            self.posicion[0] += 1
                            movido = True
                    else:
                        if self.posicion[0] == 0:
                            xory = random.randint(0, 1)
                            rand = random.randint(0, 1)
                        else:
                            self.posicion[0] -= 1
                            movido = True
                else:
                    if rand == 0:
                        if self.posicion[1] == 4:
                            xory = random.randint(0, 1)
                            rand = random.randint(0, 1)
                        else:
                            self.posicion[1] += 1
                            movido = True
                    else:
                        if self.posicion[1] == 0:
                            xory = random.randint(0, 1)
                            rand = random.randint(0, 1)
                        else:
                            self.posicion[1] -= 1
                            movido = True

    def pista(self, gato):
        if self.posicion[0] == gato.posicion[0] and self.posicion[1] > gato.posicion[1]:
            print("El raton está al Sur")
        elif self.posicion[0] > gato.posicion[0] and self.posicion[1] > gato.posicion[1]:
            print("El raton está al Sureste")
        elif self.posicion[0] > gato.posicion[0] and self.posicion[1] == gato.posicion[1]:
            print("El raton está al Este")
        elif self.posicion[0] > gato.posicion[0] and self.posicion[1] < gato.posicion[1]:
            print("El raton está al Noreste")
        elif self.posicion[0] == gato.posicion[0] and self.posicion[1] < gato.posicion[1]:
            print("El raton está al Norte")
        elif self.posicion[0] < gato.posicion[0] and self.posicion[1] < gato.posicion[1]:
            print("El raton está al Noroeste")
        elif self.posicion[0] < gato.posicion[0] and self.posicion[1] == gato.posicion[1]:
            print("El raton está al Oeste")
        elif self.posicion[0] > gato.posicion[0] and self.posicion[1] < gato.posicion[1]:
            print("El raton está al Suroeste")


class Queso:

    posicion = [0, 0]

    def spawn(self):
        self.posicion = [random.randint(0, 4), random.randint(0, 4)]

    def getposicion(self):
        return self.posicion


def imprimirmapa():
    for y in range(0, 5):
        for x in range(0, 5):
            print("[", end="", flush=True)
            if gato.posicion[0] == x and gato.posicion[1] == y:
                print("O", end="", flush=True)
            else:
                print("X", end="", flush=True)

            if x == 4:
                print("]")
            else:
                print("]", end="", flush=True)


gato = Gato()
raton = Raton()
queso = Queso()

gato.spawn()
raton.spawn()
queso.spawn()

while gato.posicion[0] == raton.posicion[0] and gato.posicion[1] == raton.posicion[1]:
    print("Spawn Failed!")
    raton.spawn()


ganado = False

while not ganado:
    raton.pista(gato)
    imprimirmapa()
    gato.moverse(input("Introduce la dirección en que te quieres mover (norte, sur, este, oeste)"))
    if gato.detectarcolisionraton(raton):
        print("Has ganado")
        ganado = True
    elif gato.detectarcolisionqueso(queso):
        queso.posicion = [-1, -1]
        print("Encontraste el QUESO")
        raton.pista(gato)
        gato.moverse(input("Introduce la dirección en que te quieres mover (norte, sur, este, oeste)"))
        raton.pista(gato)
        gato.moverse(input("Introduce la dirección en que te quieres mover (norte, sur, este, oeste)"))
        raton.pista(gato)
        queso.spawn()
        gato.moverse(input("Introduce la dirección en que te quieres mover (norte, sur, este, oeste)"))
    raton.moverse(gato)
```

Comment: Check all your `while` loops. Is it possible that within one of your `while` loops, you never change the `while` condition?

Comment: I would strongly recommend trying to debug this yourself before coming here. Did you use an IDE with a debugger, and step through each line to see where the infinite loop was happening? If not, I'd again strongly recommend learning how to do that, since it will be a necessary tool for every programmer at some point.

Comment: Just a guess, but it seems to get stuck in this loop: `while not movido:` you set `movido = False`, and `while not movido` evaluates to `while True` and never set `movido = False` so it's continually checking `while True`. Possibly should the loop be `while movido:` ... ?

Comment: @RandomDavis Already tried to debug it though I'm not very familiar with pycharm (which is the ide I'm using), I'm a Java guy haha

Comment: @davedwards I tried to change the condition to movido == False but it's still doing the same thing, and I do change it to true after I type in the north/south/east/west thing.

It was working before, I am really confused

Comment: No I meant try changing the while loop to `while movido:`

Comment: @davedwards I tried it but it never enters into the loop in the first place as movido is set to False by default and doing while movido: is like doing while movido == True:

Comment: @OscarArranz You say it was working before, PyCharm has a "History" tool that you can browse previous saved versions of your script. Right-click the script on the top (or in the file list on the side) and look for "`Local History`" -> "`Show History`", and select the any of the old versions and see if you can find the one where it was working.  Or possibly the answer below can help fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Raton` class, in `moverse()`, you have `if gato.getmovimientos() % 3 == 0 is True`, then this leads to changing `movido` from `False` to `True`, however you have no statement for when `gato.getmovimientos()` is `False`, which is why you have an infinite loop.